# Get Data into textarea from mysql

Tags: php, html, sql

I have some issues with my project.
I want to retrive into a text area all info from a selected column.

With this text area i need to do this things:

1. get all info from specific column.
2. If i delete a record from textarea need to delete from database specific line
3. IF i upload new line need to add a new record in the post table.

At this moment i have this code , but i stopped to pct.1 because i receive in textarea just the last record from my specific column.

I am open to new suggestion and yours idea.

Code:

```
<?php
include "header.php";
include "assets/require_admin_logged_in.php";

$post_product_id = $_GET['selected_product'];

$verify_product_id = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM website_products WHERE product_id='$post_product_id'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($verify_product_id)){
$product_price = $row["price"];
$product_name = $row["name"];
$product_description = $row["description"];
}
$product_table_name = $post_product_id.'_stock';


$get_product_stock_info = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT stock_product FROM $product_table_name ");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_product_stock_info)){
    $product_name_stock = $row["stock_product"];
    $product_table_name = $post_product_id.'_stock';
}

?>
<?php


?>

    <center>
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 110px; width: 40%">

    <center><h2 style="padding-bottom: 20px; font-size: 25px;">Add Stock To <b><?php echo $product_name; ?></b></h2></center>
    <br>


    <form action="" method="POST">

        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea required class="form-control" aria-describedby="stockHelp" rows="20"><?php echo $product_name_stock;?></textarea><br><br>
        </div>

        <center><button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload New Stock</button></center>

    </form>

    <br>

<?php
include "footer.php";
?>
```

Comment: PLEASE use prepared statements (https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.
Another question: Why do you have a separate table for each product id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each iteration you are overwriting your `$product_name_stock` value, this is why you only see one. I see two options here:

**Using an array and then [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the entries**

```
$product_name_stocks_array = array(); // stocks must be an array

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_product_stock_info)){
    $product_name_stocks_array[] = $row["stock_product"]; // add stock to array
    $product_table_name = $post_product_id.'_stock';
}

// the next line will add a new line after every entry and transform array to string
$product_name_stocks = implode("\n", $product_name_stocks_array);
```

or: **directly concatenating your results and removing the first newline with [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)**

```
$product_name_stocks = ""; // stocks must be a string

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_product_stock_info)){
    $product_name_stocks = $product_name_stocks . "\n" . $row["stock_product"]; // add stock to array
    $product_table_name = $post_product_id.'_stock';
}

$product_name_stocks = substr($product_name_stocks, 2); // skips the first \n newline
```